Find group homomorphism
Suppose I have two finite discrete groups, F and G.  How can I computationally determine if there exists a group homomorphism between the two?
For example, we might have F = the Klein Four Group, and G = the Cyclic group of order 4.  (These are not homomorphic.)
As another example, suppose F = the cyclic group of order 3 ($\{0,1,2\}$, denoted $C_3$) and G = the cyclic group of order 6 ($\{0,1,2,3,4,5 \}$ or $C_6$).  One can form the homomorphism from F to G as:  $0 \mapsto 0, 1 \mapsto 2, 2 \mapsto 4$, which preserves group structure and is a homomorphism.
I have searched through documentation, without success.

This kind of problem should be handled by special purpose software such as GAP - Groups, Algorithms, Programming - a System for Computational Discrete Algebra. If you want to do it in Mathematica, you need to specify how to present F and G in Mathematica.

Here's some code that I have used for small finite groups. It assumes that the groups are given by their multiplication tables. Mathematica has some built-in group structures such as DihedralGroup, AbelianGroup, and others. The function GroupMultiplicationTable then returns a choice of multiplication table.
The code looks for all maps h that take an integer (element of G) and return an integer (element of H) such that the group homomorphism equations h[ GProd[ i, j ] ] == HProd[ h[i], h[j] ] are satisfied. This is done using a tree search, i.e. via backtracking.
Note that at the end I replace h by Identity so you obtain maps from integers to integers. These integers denote the position of an element in the group multiplication table and will therefore always start from 1. So for the cyclic group with 4 elements we get 1,2,3,4 as group element labels, even though it is more intuitive to use 0,1,2,3. I'm afraid that you will have to do the translation manually since different people use different conventions for labels and multiplication tables of groups.
GroupHomomorphisms[ G_, H_ ]:= 
    Module[{ HProd, GProd, homEquations, CompleteHom, h },
        
        (* We need GProd and HProd to be unevaluated for non-integers
           otherwise we get array errors  *)
        GProd[ i_Integer, j_Integer ] := G[[ i, j ]];
        HProd[ i_Integer, j_Integer ] := H[[ i, j ]];
        
        homEquations =
            Flatten @ 
            Table[
                h[ GProd[ i, j ] ] == HProd[ h[ i ], h[ j ] ],
                { i, 2, Length @ G },
                { j, 2, Length @ G }
            ];  
        
        (* Backtracking function *)
        (* If no unknowns and no equations left: Sow the solution *)
        CompleteHom[ {}, {}, rules_ ] := 
            Sow[ rules ];
            
        (* Otherwise: If equations are false: return nothing. 
           If not false: for each possible value: set unknown equal 
           to that value, update equations, unknowns, and rules 
           and continue.  *)
        CompleteHom[ eqns_, unknowns_, rules_ ] := 
            Module[{newRule,newEqns},
                If[ MemberQ[ False ] @ eqns, Return @ {} ];
                
                Do[
                    newRule = First[unknowns] -> m; 
                    
                    CompleteHom[ 
                        DeleteCases[True] @ ReplaceAll[newRule] @ eqns
                        ,
                        Rest @ unknowns
                        ,
                        Append[ newRule ] @ rules
                    ]
                    , 
                    { m, Length @ H }
                ]
                
            ];
        
        Reap[
            CompleteHom[ 
                DeleteCases[True] @ ReplaceAll[{ h[ 1 ] -> 1 }] @ homEquations,
                Table[ h[i], { i, 2, Length[G] } ],
                { h[ 1 ] -> 1 }
            ]
        ][[2]] /. h -> Identity /. { { x__ } } :> { x }
    ];

For your first example we find that
G1 = GroupMultiplicationTable @ AbelianGroup[{2, 2}];
H1 = GroupMultiplicationTable @ CyclicGroup[4];
GroupHomomorphisms[ G1, H1 ]

returns
{
  {1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1}, 
  {1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 3}, 
  {1 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 3}, 
  {1 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 1}
}

From this result it can be seen that there are no isomoprhisms between the two since the values of each list do not range over 1, 2, 3, 4.
For the second example we find that
G2 = GroupMultiplicationTable @ CyclicGroup[3];
H2 = GroupMultiplicationTable @ CyclicGroup[6];
GroupHomomorphisms[ G2, H2 ]

returns
{
  {1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1}, 
  {1 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 5}, 
  {1 -> 1, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 3}
}

